# ionCube - Works on CLI but not with HTTP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, command-line-interface, ioncube

I'm trying to install ionCube loader on a CentOS 5 machine.

I've installed php 5.3 & ionCube loader through the atomic yum repo.

when i check on the command line, php says ionCube loads fine:

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: Apr 19 2011 12:28:40) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd.
```

but the loader isn't picked up when I run a php script via http (?)

phpinfo() shows in the "Additional .ini files parsed" that /etc/php.d/ioncube.ini is indeed loaded and parse but ionCube doesn't work; ionCube encrypted files are shown as is rather than parsed and the phpinfo page shows no mention of ionCube (apart from the parsed ini file).

I've restarted apache.

What's missing?

**EDIT:** The ioncube.ini file content is:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
```

**EDIT 2**: just tried zend gard loader and it worked right away. ionCube does not. Weird

Answer (score 0):

See https://superuser.com/questions/290350/ioncube-works-on-cli-but-not-with-http/